# A continuous nonconstant function has uncountable range

Tags: real-analysis

How would I prove that if I have a function $f$ on $\mathbb R^1$, that is continuous and non constant,  that its range is non countable?

---

Here's my thought.

Let $f$ be a continuous, non constant function on $\mathbb R^1$. Because $f$ is non constant, it is not connected. Therefore, there exists a subset of $\mathbb R^1$ that is both open and closed within the preimage of $f$. Therefore, either the domain or range of $f$ is disconnected. Thus there is not always an intermediate value on all intervals in $\mathbb R^1$...

Am I close at all?

Comment: use the intermediate value theorem

Comment: Can I do this as a consequence of the metric space not being connected?

Comment: Sure, can you prove that a countable subset of $\mathbb R$ having at least two points is disconnected?

Comment: I thought it was disconnected by virtue of being nonconstant. Thus, either the domain or range is also disconnected. Therefore, it wouldn't take on all values of f (a) and f (b). Hence there would be no median value?

Comment: Nonconstant just means there exist $a, b \in \mathbb R$ so that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. A constant function is one of the form $f(x) = c$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, with $c \in \mathbb R$ fixed. It's not clear what you mean by $f$ being disconnected, but it certainly isn't standard terminology.

Comment: That makes sense!  Thanks!

Comment: F being connected was a phone typo. I meant the metric. But how would I go on to prove the range is uncountable?

Comment: @JosephPaul glad to hear it! I'll post an answer addressing the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $a<b$ be two points so that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. Then either $f(a)<f(b)$ or $f(a)>f(b)$. Let's discuss the case $f(a)<f(b)$, and the other case can be handled similarly.

Let $c \in \mathbb R$ be any number in the range $f(a)<c<f(b)$. Note that there are uncountably many such $c$. Now what does the intermediate value theorem tell you?

Comment: It tells me there should be a c that f maps to. But if there are uncountable c, then ran f is uncountable. .

Comment: It tells you that $f$ maps to *every* such $c$. Ergo your conclusion.

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is non-constant. hence range of f contains more than one element. R is connected and $f $ is continuous.hence $f(R)$ is connected.It contains at least two distinct points hence $f(R)$ is uncountable as theorem says that connected set with two distinct points is uncountable.