# Cardinalilty of range of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cardinals

Is it true that the cardinality of the range of any non-constant continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is equal to cardinality of the set of real numbers?

If so, how do you prove it?

Comment: Hint: Does the image necessarily contain an interval? If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: There is, I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: Hint: If $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then it is uniquely determined by $f \restriction \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It's not a duplicate of that question also Stefan's hint is more applicable to the other question.

Comment: @Mathematician42: Yes, you're right. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: No problem, it might be a duplicate of another though but I couldn't find it immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A continuous nonconstant function has uncountable range](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967417/a-continuous-nonconstant-function-has-uncountable-range)

Comment: Although I think the answer here is better/more detailed. Maybe somebody else knows how to deal with that.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non-constant continuous function. Then there exist numbers $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a\neq b$, $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. We may assume that $a<b$. By the intermediate value theorem, the interval $[a,b]$ belongs to the image.

Hence $(a,b)\subset \text{Im}(f)\subset \mathbb{R}$. It follows that $|(a,b)|\leq |\text{Im}(f)|\leq |\mathbb{R}|$, where $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of $A$. Since $|(a,b)|=|\mathbb{R}|$ we must have that $|\text{Im}(f)|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

To see that $|(a,b)|=|\mathbb{R}|$, first show that any two finite length intervals are bijective, then $|(a,b)|=|(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})|$ and $\tan:(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection.

Comment: Mathematician 42, can the same proof be applied to open intervals? Like (a,b), (a,b], [a,b)

Comment: Well yeah, there are all subsets of $[a,b]$.

Comment: But from that how do we know that there is a bijection to the real line to show that the cardinality is equal to that of the real lines?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain that as well.

Comment: What does this answer prove, exactly?

Comment: Can I duplicate the above proof if i were to change the question from continuous functions to polynomial functions? Since polynomials are also continuous

Comment: Yes, you can!!! (I just needed three exclamation marks to get the minimal length).

Comment: @Starfall: It answers the question asked by the OP, the linked question is a different question.

Comment: 3 exclamation marks?

Comment: Exactly. three. (now I needed the .'s to get to 15 characters)

Comment: What about the set of integrable functions? If A is the set of all integrable functions, is the card of A still equal to that of real?

Comment: That's a completely different question. You asked about the cardinality of the image of certain functions, now you are asking about the cardinality of a set of functions, that's very different. You should ask a new question if you're interested in that, be sure to take a look at the linked question first.